# Issue with using globals when window is opened and destroyed repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am building a small application.

When one runs this minimal program, he/she will see that there is a login button on the start screen (*startS*). When one clicks it, the window is destroyed and a new window is created (*homeP*), which has a button for opening up a textbox and a logout button. The logout button when clicked, destroys *homeP* and again starts *startS*.

Steps to Reproduce my Issue:

Click Login -> Click "Enter Grades" -> Click Logout -> Click Login -> Click "Enter Grades" -> Error: (`can't invoke "grid" command: application has been destroyed`)

This happens because, I have been using `globals`. As one can see, I want to prevent frames from stacking up on one another so I check if the *eGrade* frame has been made or not (i.e. there in the `globals()` or not). If yes then just place the existing one. But when the page is destroyed, it is still in the `globals()` and thus, it will give an error if we try to just place it again as the widget has been destroyed.

```
from tkinter import *

def Start():
    global startS
    startS = Tk()

    loginButton = Button(startS, text='Login', bg='blue', fg='white', command=Login)
    loginButton.grid()

    startS.mainloop()

def Home():
    global homeP
    homeP = Tk()

    enterButton = Button(homeP, text='Enter Grades', bg='blue', fg='white', command=enterG)
    enterButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    logoutButton = Button(homeP, text='LogOut', bg='brown', fg='white', command=Logout)
    logoutButton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

    homeP.mainloop()

def enterG():
    global homeP
    global eGrade

    if 'eGrade' not in globals(): #Prevent Frames from stacking up on one another
        eGrade = Frame(homeP)

        enterGrades = Text(eGrade, width=64, height=10)
        enterGrades.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ewns")

        eGrade.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ns")
    else:
        eGrade.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ns")

    # for name, value in globals().copy().items():
    #   print(name, value)

def Logout():
    global homeP
    homeP.destroy()
    Start()

def Login():
    global startS
    startS.destroy()
    Home()

Start()
```

So I wanted to know some suggestions from the experts on this topic as to whether using globals is a good practice and how can I circumvent this issue ?

Comment: 1st problem that stands out is multiple `Tk()` instances. You should not do this.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Okay. Sorry, just a beginner. I would like to know a bit more on that.

Comment: Yep. I am working on an answer it will take a few min.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason you are getting this error is when you log out the first time you destroy the container holding the text widget. Even though the widget (frame) exist in the global namespace you have destroyed the tkinter instance it was assigned to. Thus can no longer be applied to it.

This is a direct results of recreating `Tk()` instances instead of using just one instance and managing the data inside of it.

My example will condense your code into something much simpler and should provide a good starting ground for you. What we will do here is create a global tracking variable for the text in your textbox. This will allow us to save the data when we logout and then reapply the data when we log back in. Thus keeping the old text.

```
import tkinter as tk

def Home():
    clear_widgets()
    tk.Button(root, text='Enter Grades', bg='blue', fg='white', command=enterG).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    tk.Button(root, text='LogOut', bg='brown', fg='white', command=logout).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

def enterG():
    global txt
    if txt == None:
        txt = tk.Text(root, width=64, height=10)
        txt.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ns")
        txt.insert(1.0, text_data)

def logout():
    global txt, text_data
    text_data = txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    clear_widgets()
    txt = None
    tk.Button(root, text='Login', bg='blue', fg='white', command=login).grid(row=0, column=0)

def clear_widgets():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

def login():
    # some method of checking login credentials.
    Home()

root = tk.Tk()
text_data = ""
tk.Button(root, text='Login', bg='blue', fg='white', command=login).grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

However sooner or later you will want to start coding in OOP. This is a good option and it will allow us to avoid global's all-together. In a class we can use something called a class attribute that can be accessed from any method (a class function) without needing to define global.

Here is a class example of your code.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text_data = ""
        self.txt = None
        tk.Button(self, text='Login', bg='blue', fg='white', command=self.login).grid(row=0, column=0)

    def home(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        tk.Button(self, text='Enter Grades', bg='blue', fg='white', command=self.enter_g).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        tk.Button(self, text='LogOut', bg='brown', fg='white', command=self.logout).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")

    def enter_g(self):
        if self.txt == None:
            self.txt = tk.Text(self, width=64, height=10)
            self.txt.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ns")
            self.txt.insert(1.0, self.text_data)

    def logout(self):
        self.text_data = self.txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.txt = None
        tk.Button(self, text='Login', bg='blue', fg='white', command=self.login).grid(row=0, column=0)

    def clear_widgets(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

    def login(self):
        # some method of checking login credentials.
        self.home()

Example().mainloop()
```

Comment: Wanted to ask, what if I press the "Enter Grades" button multiple times. It will keep on overriding, isn't it? Even if the textbox is already open. Also the reason why I was using a frame for the textbox was because there were other widgets also inside the frame, but not required for the Demo.

Comment: @Miraj50 added a fix for that. We can simple keep a tracking variable to see if the text widget exist or not.

Comment: @Miraj50 Yes you are correct, good catch. Bad habit. Most of my if statements involve `!=`.

Comment: I am starting to understand it bit by bit. I wanted to know with this start, I can introduce frames instead of the `Text` and do the same thing, right? As I need to insert some more widgets for my application.

Comment: @Miraj50 yes you can use frames for any widgets you need. I just simplified your example to make it easier to understand the workflow.

Comment: Think I figured it out. Great help from you. Thank you very much. Used to see answers with OOP. Never realized its importance until now. Accepting it. Hope I have your permission to get back to you in the future if I face a problem :)

Comment: @Miraj50 I am always watching the Tkinter tag. I am sure myself or one of the other very skilled people out there will be able to assist :D. Happy coding!